# Postgresql insert has more expressions than target

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert

I know this has been asked and answered but I'm still unable to get this trigger function to insert correctly. I know I have the same number of values being inserted but keep getting the `has more expressions than target`. The only difference in columns structure, is that namespace2.t1 has one extra column that is not included in namespace1.t1; which is why I can't just `SELECT * from namespace2.t1`

```
CREATE 
OR REPLACE FUNCTION upsert_trigger_function() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$ 
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO
    namespace1.t1 (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, col11) 
    SELECT
(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, col11) 
    FROM
      namespace2.t1 
      ON CONFLICT (col1) DO 
      UPDATE
      SET
        col2 = namespace2.t1.col2,
        ... 
      WHERE
        namespace2.t1.col1 = col1;
RETURN NEW;
END;
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

And my trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER upsert_namespace1_t1 after INSERT 
OR 
UPDATE
  ON namespace2.t2 FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE upsert_trigger_function();
```

Comment: Can you try to reproduce this in a fiddle (e.g. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11)

Comment: Get rid of the useless (and in this case wrong) parentheses around the column list in the SELECT statement.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, when I remove that It tells me I have an invalid reference to FROM t1

Comment: That is a different error (and thus question), but you probably want `col2 = EXCLUDED.col2, ...` in the UPDATE part.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, cool. Will do. Thank you for the link to the question. I wasn't able to find that answer. Now I understand the return I was getting. Thanks :D